# How do I create a s3 bucket, IAM user with full access to S3 and how do I pass the users credentials to my application?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using Amazon cloudformation template https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/PHPHelloWorld.template to setup my application. I need to create a S3 bucket and a IAM user with full access to S3. My PHP application would need the credentials of the user created to upload files to s3.

How do I create a s3 bucket, IAM user with full access to S3 and how do I pass the users credentials to my application ?

Also I have to install the Amazon PHP SDK and some softwares, what are the entries I need to add to the UserData section of PHPHelloWorld.template

Thank you

Comment: Hope this link is useful:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/index.html?quickref-s3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [example template list](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/) contains a [template for giving an IAM user full access](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/S3Bucket_Lockdown_to_IAM_User.template).

Somewhat counter-intuitively you don't set any properties on the S3 bucket, it's either on an S3 bucket policy, or the IAM user.